# How do I use schedule to set my script run twice a day? - python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I can't find a way to run my script more than once a day, at a specifically time.

```
schedule.every().day.at('22:00').do(main)
```

it works.

```
schedule.every().day.at('13:00').do(main)
schedule.every().day.at('22:00').do(main)
```

Doesn't work at all.

Any sugguestion? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your script to the crontab. You can access crontab by typing `crontab -e` on your terminal. Simply add 2 cron entries to your tab corresponding to the times you need. Try http://www.cronmaker.com/ to create your cron. For example, `00 01,13 * * *` will run your script/command at 1 AM and 1 PM.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it work using python schedule ?